# convergence of sequence with factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

i want to study wether the sequence

$$u_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^nk!$$

converges or not. I didn't get the trick yet, do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges to $1$.

*1st step:*
$$0\le \frac{1!+\dots+(n-1)!}{n!}\le\frac{(n-2)\cdot(n-2)!+ (n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{n-2}{n(n-1)}+\frac1n\to 0$$
*2nd step:*
$$\frac{1!+\dots+n!}{n!}=\frac{1!+\dots+(n-1)!}{n!}+1\to 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Approximate**) For sufficiently large values of n,

$∑k! = 1! + 2! + 3! + ... + (n-2)! + (n-1)! + n! ≈ n!$

**Exact**) $n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * (n-2) * (n-1) * n$

$k! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * (k-2) * (k-1) * k$

$\frac{k!}{n!} = \frac{1}{(k+1) * (k+2) * (k+3) * ... * (n-2) * (n-1) * n}$

At n = 1000, $∑\frac{k!}{n!} = 1 + \frac{1}{1000} + \frac{1}{1000*999} + \frac{1}{1000*999*998} + ... + \frac{1}{1000!}$

At n = 10000, $∑\frac{k!}{n!} = 1 + \frac{1}{10000} + \frac{1}{10000*9999} + \frac{1}{10000*9999*9998} + ... + \frac{1}{10000!}$

Answer (score 0):

Stolz-Cesaro will finish this off quickly, but here's a hint for a home-made proof: For large $n,$ $n! < \sum_{k=1}^{n}k! < n! +(n-1)! + (n-2)(n-2)!$